# When putting data into elasticsearch, how do you handle fields that sometimes have different structures?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm getting several mapping Exceptions when trying to insert data from my mongoDb into Elastic. After some investigative work, it seems that the error comes from the fact that I have a field in my db that is sometimes and array of strings, while other times an array of objects.

Meaning, for some documents in mongo it will have this:

```
{"my_field" : ["one", "two"]
```

while others

```
{"my_field": [{"key":"value", "key2":"value"}, {"key":"value", "key2":"value"}, ...]
```

I'm having a difficult time in pinning down how exactly this situation is handled in Elastic.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to massage the data before it is indexed so that it does conform to elasticsearch's rules. One approach is for my_field to be a nested document - for one document you might have

```
{"my_field": {"string_value": ["one", "two"]}}
```

and for another

```
{"my_field": {"doc_value": {"key":"value", "key2":"value"}}}
```

This assumes that the values for key and key2 will always have the same type and that there is a small number of possible keys in this document. If this document contains arbitrary data you might be better off indexing as

```
{"my_field": [{"key": "key1", "string_value": "value"},
            {"key": "key2", "int_value": "123"}]}
```

As for how you massage, one option is to do this before you send the data to elasticsearch. The downside is that the the _source attribute will obviously contained the transformed data.

Another approach is to send the data to elasticsearch as-is, but to have a [transform](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/mapping-transform.html) in the mapping that elasticsearch will run to transform the data before indexing.

Comment: Could you possibly provide a small example transform? From the linked docs, I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how the conversion is to be done. Woud it be something like `if (ctx._source['my_field'][0] isinstance String) ctx.source['my_new_field'] = ctx._source['my_field']`?

Comment: that looks about right. As is this obviously leaves the original field there, I think you can mark it as not to be indexed (in the mapping), not sure about deleting from _source)